# force sips command to write output to stdout

Tags: sips

I wrote a script that convert a icns file to png and then encode the png with base64.

I could do it in 2 steps:

- `sips -s format png test.icns -o test.png`
- `base64 -w0 test.png`

But since `test.png` is just an intermediary file, I'd like to pipe the output of the 1st command directly to `base64`, how do I do that?

Note that `sips` doesn't seem to support `/dev/stdout` as the argument of `-o`.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i '/private/var/root/Desktop/Volume limiter.app/Contents/Resources/applet.icns' -c:v png -f rawvideo - | base64`

Comment: Using zsh: `(){ sips -s format png test.icns --out $1; base64 $1 } =()`

Comment: @robertklep does `=()` at the end invoke the function just defined? Where can I find more info about `=()`? Thanks!

Comment: @TeddyC `=(command)` will return the name of a temporary file that contains the output of `command`. However, it also works without a command, and will create (and return the name of) an empty temp file. That filename is then passed to the function defined by `() { … }` as its first argument (`$1`). It's documented in the zshexpn manpage.

Comment: @robertklep this zsh trick is absolutely amazing! It is going to save me so much work. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sips` utility does not support outputting to stdout unfortunately, so you cannot directly pipe the resulting file into another program. And as you have already tested, it also does not support using `/dev/stdout` or a named pipe or similar, as it will recreate the file when outputting.

However, you can use ordinary shell scripting "tricks" to make a "one-liner" for combining the commands if you wish to do so:

```
 sips -s format png test.icns -o __$$ && base64 __$$ && rm __$$
```

Note that this is for Bash, and that it will create and delete a temporary file named __.

Also note that I have removed the `-w0` parameter in your question from the `base64` command. That is a parameter you would use on for example the Linux version of the `base64` command, but the macOS command does not have such a parameter. Indeed that wrapping behaviour you request with that parameter is already on by default on macOS.

Comment: I installed `coreutils` with `brew` and linked `gbase64` to a dir in the `$PATH` before `/usr/bin` and removed the leading `g`. :)

Comment: Does the oneliner produce a file with the name `__$$` and then remove it?

Comment: No, the file is named a number that changes with the process id - i.e. prevents a conflict if you have multiple Tabs and run the line multiple times.